# More efficient way of reading a CSV file in Python with different delimeter

Tags: python

I am a high school student, so please don't mind if this question is stupid, but Is there a more efficient way of reading a csv file in python than using the csv module and file reader. Also, is there a way to specify a different delimiter or can it only read with "," as a delimiter.

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    fields = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: The csv module is pretty efficient and I don't think you're going to improve on it.  You can specify a different delimiter as part of the formatting parameters: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the "pandas" library to read a csv file (along with sql tables etc) and store the data as a pandas "dataframe", you may use these dataframes directly in plotly and prophet. You can also convert these dataframes into numpy arrays or lists based on the necessity.

You can install pandas using the following command:

```
pip install pandas
```

or you may install it in a conda environment using:

```
conda activate name_of_your_environment
conda install pandas
```

After that you can read a csv file using the following code to read a csv file and specify any delimeters:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Path to File/filename.csv",delimiter = "\t")
```

To change it into an numpy.ndarray you may use the "to_numpy()" method of the dataframe.

Similarly, to change it into a list you may use the "tolist()" method of the dataframe.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delimiter parameter of csv.reader to set the delimiter:

```
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\n')
```

The documentation for the CSV Python module should help you: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html